# What determines whether a monoamine neurotransmitter is recycled or broken down by MAO?

Tags: neuroscience, dopamine, neuro-transmitters, serotonin

When a neurotransmitter detaches from the receptor and is returned to the neuron via the transporter, what are the primary factors that influence whether that molecule is re-stored in a vesicle by VMAT2 or broken down by MAO A or B? Is it simply the relative abundance of those compounds?